# BDD framework to work for with good reports

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd, behat

My project requirements are

```
  1.The framework must produce detailed Step Reports  - which can be sent to the client through email. 
  2.The execution time must be less 
  3.Easy to write
```

I know behat and Cucumber

Please suggest me which framework is good ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say Behat+Mink+Selenium combination. I've been using for very long time.

1. Behat will give you [report](http://behat.readthedocs.org/en/v2.5/guides/6.cli.html#format-options) as you wanted. We always send reports to clients where every single line is printed and either marked as success or failure. At the end of it, you get a full result where you can see overall report.
   e.g. `bin/behat @YourBundleName -f pretty,html --out ,report-path/behat.html`. You can even get screen-shots of failed steps.
2. Every program can be considered as fast or slow. Result will depend on how you do things. You have a lot of options to make behat tests run fast. e.g. if you use [phantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/) to run the tests and symfony2 as default session.
3. Behat uses [Gherkin](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/1.gherkin.html) language which is easy to understand and write. You don't have to be a programmer at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One framework known for its pretty reports is Concordion. Please, have a look at the example to view one such report: http://concordion.org/Example.html

The Java version of Concordion utilizes JUnit to execute its tests. So you get a good integration in your development environment. Concordion support multiple technologies such as .NET, Ruby, Python, etc. http://concordion.org/Ports.html
Which technology are you using?

Concordion based on specification by example has been designed with a short learning-curve as a top priority. The purposely small command-set is simple to learn: http://concordion.org/Tutorial.html